# Convert linq statement to sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, t-sql

I am deprecating a project from linq coding back to sql stored procedures.  (My company refuses to upgrade our sql 2000 database.)  I am stuck on this current code trying to convert it to sql.  Can anyone help with this?

```
Dim ICD9Codes = (
From a In Linq2Db.ICD9Codes
Where IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Variable1), 1 = 1, a.Code.StartsWith(Variable1))
Select a).ToList
```

I am stuck on the 'IIF' statements converting it where the 'where' clause only uses the if statement if the value is not null.

Comment: If you use linqpad to run that query against your database, you can flip to the SQL tab and see what the statement actually generated, from there you can modify to suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert this into a SP you'll need to make `Variable1` a parameter. The `IIf` part could be addressed in the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [procedure_name] @variable1 varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM ID9Codes
    WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@variable1, '')))) = 0
        OR Code lIKE @Variable1 + '%'
END
```

Comment: Works perfectly... Thank you SOOO MUCH!!!  My original code was actually much more complex than this snippet I gave, but this final piece helped me to solve the entire Linq query.  Thank you again!